# Find a pattern in a string object then extract substring

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, text, find

I want to extract a substring from a string object. The text I want to extract is price data with € at the end. The price can be 3-digit or 4-digit.

```
text = "xxxxxx; AAAA€; xxxxxxx"
```

or

```
text = "xxxxxx; AAA€; xxxxxxx"
```

My code:

```
position = text.find("€")
price_to_clean = text[(position - 4):(position - 1)]
price = price_to_clean.rpartition(";")[-1]
```

My thinking is to search until €, then reversely extract 4 digits( the substring will be "AAAA€" or ";AAA€"). Then remove the semicolon from the later one. I want to know if there is a better way to achieve this. E.g. finding the € then reversely search until a semicolon?

Comment: Have you considered regex?

Comment: Are the pieces always delimited by semicolons like this? And is the price always the second one? If so, it's hard to get simpler than, say, `text.split('; ')[1][:-1]`. Although it seems like you may be trying to parse lines from a CSV file, in which case you might want to use the `csv` module, or at some point you're going to run into a column like `"This column has ;;; semicolons so it's quoted"`, or, worse, `This column is plain old text but it happens to have 555€ in it`.

Comment: @Mr.T No I haven't. I just tried re.search and it worked. Thanks!Thanks!

Comment: @abarnet Thanks for taking time to look into my question. No it was a string object from a html file. It's pretty messy with all kinds of signs. I couldn't convert it to any type of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex. `re.search`

**Ex:**

```
import re
text = "xxxxxx; 1000€; xxxxxxx"
m = re.search("(?P<price>\d+€)", text)
if m:
    print(m.group('price'))
```

**Output:**

```
1000€
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks a lot!